# How to send props to sub routed-component with React-Router and React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, jsx, react-router-redux

I'm creating website with React + React-Router and React-redux. This is my store and reducer:

```jsx
const defaultState = {
    posts: [{key:0, title: 'Default post', text: 'Every visitor is welcome!'}]
};

const store = createStore(
    (state = defaultState, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
);
```

i don't have any action yet, i will add it later. however, back to the point, this is App Component which is entry point of React App.

```jsx
const App = React.createClass({
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React Router + Redux Blog</h1>

                <ul>
                    <li><IndexLink to="/">Main</IndexLink></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/posts">Posts</Link></li>
                </ul>

                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

and this App component will connect with Redux-Router's connect method:

```jsx
const ConnectedApp = connect( (state) => {
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    };
})(App);
```

now, the last, i will give Router component instead of ConnectedApp inside of Provider, and use ConnectedApp as index component.

```jsx
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={ConnectedApp}>
                <IndexRoute component={Main} />
                <Route path="about" component={About} />
                <Route path="posts" component={Posts} >
                    <IndexRoute component={PostsMain} posts={[]} />
                    <Route path="write" component={PostsWrite} />
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

now, this is the problem. i want to send Redux Store states into sub component(PostsMain or PostsWrite) as Props, but i don't know how to pass it. every sub component might be rendered is decided by React Router, and each component doesn't have any stored state by Redux.

I saw some modules like React-Router-Redux, Redux-Router, but I want to do it without them. If someone knows how to do it, please gimme advice and that will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want some components in your tree to receive Redux's state data, you have to make them "container components" by using React-Redux library’s `connect()` function.

For example, you could write a "PostsMain" container like this:

```jsx
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PostsMainComponent from '../components/posts_main_component.jsx';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        // the desired props calculated from the store's state, for example:
        posts: state.posts,
    };
};

const PostsMainContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(PostsMainComponent);

export default PostsMainContainer;
```

Then use it in your routes declaration like this:

```jsx
<IndexRoute component={PostsMainContainer} />
```

You'll find detailed information about container components in [Redux's doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) and this [post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.rwlsxc3sq) by Dan Abramov.